# Designing less than and less than or equal operators for Map with value being a Set

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to come up with less than and less than or equals operators for a Map where values are Sets. These are the hints I was able to get from the Professor.

```
{A -> {1,2}, B -> {3,4}} < {A -> {1,2}, B -> {3,4}, C -> {5,6}}

{A -> {1,2}, B -> {3,4}} < {A -> {1,2}, B -> {3,4,5}}
```

My solution was this:

```
val v_compare = (x, y) => (x.keySet intersect y.keySet).forall(key => x(key) subsetOf y(key))

val v_compare_equal = v_compare
```

I am wondering can I get some hints? I don't know what should the "<=" be

Answer (score 1):

I think that actual code is off-topic here.
In general you can define a strict total order relation on (sub)sets of a known universe $U$: pick an arbitrary order for the elements of $U$ then, given two distinct subsets $X,Y$ of $U$, you can compare $X$ and $Y$ by first sorting the elements of $X$ (resp. $Y$) and then comparison the sorted version of $X$ with the sorted version of $Y$ lexicographically.

In your particular example the sets seem to contain integers, so you can just sort the set using the standard "less than" relation between integers.

To extend this total order to a map you can notice that a map is essentially a container of pairs of the form (key, value). We just defined a linear order over the values (sets), and you probably already have a natural order over the keys. Then two (key, value) pairs can be again compared lexicographically.